getting "string:format=date-time is not a valid FormattedjsonType for class java.util.String" when trying to assign date string to a field in schema
`I have a schema for a field like this :
"StartDate":{ "type":"string", "format":"date-time" }
and a mapper is as below :
"StartDate":{ "path": "policy.startDate.shortformat" }
the Date.shortFormat will give value as "05/09/2024" which is of type String.
but still I'm getting string:format=date-time is not a valid FormattedjsonType for class java.util.String when trying to assign date string to a field in schema.
I tried making changes to schema like below :


`"StartDate":{
"type":"string"
 }`



 `"StartDate":{
 "type":"string",
 "format":"date"
  } `



however none of them worked.
any help would be greatly appreciated.`

I understand that you are trying to use a specific short date format and are only interested in the date component. Guidewire's own types along with the Swagger types derived from Open API specifications are listed in the documentation (requires login). Instead of using date-time you can simply use date as its a valid Swagger JSON data type.
XXX.schema.json
"StartDate":{
 "type":"string",
 "format":"date"
}

This will format the date as 2024-05-09 i.e "yyyy-MM-dd". Please note that this is an OpenAPI standard for dates specified in  RFC 3339 - Section 5.6.
So, while you can use MM/dd/yyyy or any other format, it will not be compliant with Open API & RFC specifications and you should definitely not be specifying the format as date or date-time in this case. You can rather have the type as string and do the formatting yourself in the Rest Handler class. You may also specify the pattern property in the schema definition along with the appropriate regex to enforce your format. This way your ShortFormat property would help in the handler and you will stay compliant with Open API specs for date.
